# NSRect vs CGRect: y-axis inversion

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

So I'm trying to convert an NSRect to a CGRect. I used `NSRectToCGRect()` which copies everything over finely, but does not take into account y-origin axis.

The problem: A CGRect origin of (0,0) is the top left. NSRect origin (0,0) is bottom left.

Thus an `NSRect (0,0,100,100)` box is positioned at the bottom left of your screen, while a `CGRect (0,0,100,100)` box is placed at the top left of your screen.

I have a hack that fixes the y-origin through basic math:

```
fixedOriginY = screenHeight - NSRect.size.height - NSRect.origin.y
```

Thus the equivalent of an `NSRect (0,0,100,100)` is actually `CGRect (0,800,100,100)` (on my 900px height MBA). However I don't like this, I have a feeling it will break/have issues with retina or future complications.

Does anyone have a solution or idea on how to correctly convert NSRect to CGRect?

Comment: What makes you think CoreGraphics has the origin in the top left? I can find only indirect reference to it immediately but see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html — search for the text "The default coordinate system used by Core Graphics framework is LLO-based." (LLO = lower left origin)

Comment: The NSWindow frame property is an NSRect, so I place it at 0,0 (bottom left screen). I convert that frame to CGRect, take a screenshot using CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(displays[0], windowCGRect). The screenshot is of the top left of the screen.

Comment: Don't think of it as a difference between `CGRect` and `NSRect`. They are both just simple structs, and their values have meaning only relative to some coordinate system (either that of the code that provided or consumes the rect). In this case the difference is between AppKit's screen coordinate system, and CG's display space coordinate system, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14228817/1218876).

Comment: If all you want is to take a screenshot of a window, you can use `CGWindowListCreateImage()` instead of `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect()`.

Answer (score 6):

Whether the origin of a rectangle is at its top left or bottom left depends on the coordinate system in which you use the rectangle.  It does not depend on whether you use `CGRect` or `NSRect`.

Typically, AppKit uses coordinate systems where the lower-left corner is the origin.  Similarly, a `CGContext` that you create puts the origin at the lower left.

On the other hand, Quartz Event Services and Quartz Display Services put the origin at the upper left.  UIKit (on iOS) puts the origin at the upper left.  You can override `isFlipped` in an `NSView` subclass (on OS X) to put its origin at the upper left.

Your basic math is necessary and proper when you are converting a rectangle from a traditional (lower-left origin) to flipped (upper-left origin) coordinate system.

Comment: Window frames (e.g. `-[NSWindow frame]`) are in **screen coordinate space**, whose origin is the bottom-left corner. Quartz Display Services use either global or local **desktop coordinate spaces**, whose origins are the corresponding upper-left corners.