# Make application origin start from top left

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I'm building a cross platform application, and on most platforms, when you have a rectangle for like say a window frame position, it normally starts from the top left.

Like for say:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100); // Starts at top left corner
```

but for Macos it starts on the bottom left.

Is there any way to change this?

Also, I'm looking for this to be applied to `NSWindow`.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17058435/14351818

Comment: Ah hah! Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, although it looks like it's only for NSView. I'm looking for NSWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method in `NSWindow` that allow you to position the top-left corner of the window’s frame rectangle at a given point in screen coordinates:

```swift
func setFrameTopLeftPoint(_ point: NSPoint)
```

Or, You could just do an extra step for macOS to get the flipped `y`:

```
flippedY = screenHeight - y - windowHeight
```

Comment: But how do you get the screenHeight variable?

Comment: @ManUser123 You get the screen frame with `NSScreen.main?.frame`. Check out the [document for NSScreen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen) for for in-depth explanation.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. I'm very new to Cocoa.