# How to move the mouse cursor by using arrow keys

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouseevent, keyevent

How can I make it a key press would move my mouse cursor?
Is that possible?  I figured out how to register a key press and recognize if it's an arrow, but I'm not sure if it's possible to use that input to move a mouse

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` method should do what you want. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWarpMouseCursorPosition)

```
CGPoint target = CGPointMake(10, 50);
// where 10 is x and 50 is y
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(target);
```

When the user presses one of the arrow keys, have this run in a loop until the key is no longer depressed.

Comment: Yes that kind of worked, now when I press an arrow it moves my mouse, but it seems to always just go to the point (10,50).  Do you know how I could just make the mouse one point to the right/left?  I was thinking of finding the current mouse position and just increment it on a button press

Comment: Solved, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228078/jumping-warped-cursor/14228817#14228817